# How to replace the EOL character "\r\n" to "\n" in java

Tags: java, regex, windows, string, unix

In Windows, by default the EOL Character is "`\r\n`". But I have to change the EOL Character as "`\n`".

How can I convert the string from windows format to UNIX format?

This is the string which I am sending from windows to unix server.

```
ASPII90 ASPII90 dsascot 00000066YHDASCDRCD\t0700\t9\tASPII90\tA2185\t1234\n YRQ\t\t\t000415832\n YTRENDDRCD\t3\n
```

But in server, each \n is converted into whitespace followed by "\".(i.e)

```
YHDASCDRON>0400>9>ASPII90>A2185>128 \
```

Comment: Please post your attempt.

Comment: (And contrary to your tags, you shouldn't need a regex.)

Comment: This is the string which i am sending from windows to unix server.                                                          ASPII90 ASPII90 dsascot 00000066YHDASCDRCD\t0700\t9\tASPII90\tA2185\t1234\n
YRQ\t\t\t000415832\n
YTRENDDRCD\t3\n                                                     But in server, each \n is converted into whitespace followed by "\".(i.e)YHDASCDRON>0400>9>ASPII90>A2185>128 \

Comment: This question seems unrelated to windows EOL characters.  The example input you've provided does **NOT** contain any `\r` characters.  Neither does the example output you've provided!

Comment: You should provide some details about **how** you're sending strings from windows to a UNIX server... and how you're retrieving them (and printing them) on the server.  Are you sending requests to a servlet?  Are you using sockets?  How are we supposed to guess?

Comment: Hi jahroy, If " \n " specified in the string, it will automatically appends the " \r\n ". But i won't be visble. It will happen in back end. please read about the EOL Characters in different operating systems.

Comment: I am **very** familiar with the EOL characters used by different operating systems.  I have dealt with this issue many times.  If you're really having a simple newline issue, the answers below should solve your problem.  My guess is your problem is somewhere else.  Feel free to ignore me.

Comment: Here's [another way](https://code.google.com/p/ec2manager/source/browse/trunk/Ec2+Manager/src/com/unience/util/Dos2Unix.java?spec=svn4&r=4) to do it...

Comment: @Jahroy: While i am firing the request from putty, If i created the unix formatted request using notepad++ feature, the server accepts and giving the response. If i use windows format, Its throwing same error as what i have asked in question.

Answer (score 0):

here is an possible example Code (link to docs: [String.replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    String myString ="asdasdasdasdassdasdasd\r\n";
    System.out.println(myString.replace("\r\n","\n"));
 }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this. no use. By default, the windows will take the " \r\n " instead of " \n ". Because that is the default EOL Character in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Use notepad++

Open file in notepad++, select Edit, EOL Conversion, UNIX Format.

Done

Comment: This works fine. But i have to do it from java.

Comment: -1 This doesn't even address the OP's question (which should be closed anyways)...

Answer (score 0):

You can use BufferedReader's readLine() method to read each line.

readLine()method will remove \r\n for you

Then use BuffereWriter.write() to write this line append with '\n'

```
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("xx"));

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("yy"));

    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        writer.write(line + "\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

String is immutable, but you can create a new local string to be used as the return value:

```
String newString = originalStringNameWithManyLineBreaks.replaceAll("\r\n" , "\n");
```

now only send the value of `newString` to your server

Comment: No use. Its not working.

Comment: @SatheshSubburaj - It doesn't seem like your problem is related to EOL characters.  How exactly are you sending strings to a UNIX server?